# how to implement nginfiniteScroll for nested for loops in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I getting whole backend data at once and iterating that data while iteration im calling another API add some info to first iteration object and push that into another Array

```
      $scope.pdetails=[];
      propertyService.getPropertyData().success(function(ProObj){ // whole data from backend
        $scope.pdetails=ProObj;

         ProObj.forEach(function(PhotoId){
           var photos=[];
           PhotoId.photosId.forEach(function(Pid){
             profileService.fetchProfileImage(Pid)  //calling another API here
           .success(function(image){

             photos.push(image);
           })
           })
           ProObj.photos=photos;
           $scope.pdetails.push(ProObj); //final Array
         })

       })
```

In Application took long time display content on view so
i want load 5 object per scroll using nginfiniteScroll how to do that anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.pdetails=[];
  propertyService.getPropertyData().success(function(ProObj){ 
    $scope.pdetails=ProObj;

     angular.forEach(ProObj,function(key,PhotoId){
     if(key<4){
       var photos=[];
         angular.forEach(PhotoId.photosId,function(key,Pid){
         profileService.fetchProfileImage(Pid)
          .success(function(image){
         photos.push(image);})
       })
       ProObj.photos=photos;
       $scope.pdetails.push(ProObj);
     })
   }
   })
```

Comment: Hi akbar thanks for your reply  it throws an error like **TypeError: [object Array] is not a function**  it will fetch all data at time

Comment: @vedaI edited it, I do not have your source code to test, so I hope it works